# Does Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation edition allow use of IIS?

Tags: windows, iis

I am looking for the cheapest possible way to host a bespoke ASP.NET intranet site with Microsoft SQL Express 2008. I assume that Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation is the way to go, but does it support IIS? There will only be about 5 clients on the LAN, so the hardware limitations aren't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. No offense nbolton, but this information isn't that hard to find.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/2008-r2-editions.aspx

Click the Compare Editions link on the right, open the PDF document, and see that web services (IIS) is fully supported.

Comment: None taken! :) You're probably just more observant than me. I wasn't expecting it to be a PDF (I thought that usually MS have a web page for the feature comparison table).

Comment: That's been my experience too although I've been seeing them using pdf's more and more. Go figure.

Comment: This link goes to 2012, not 2008. Information included in the answer would be more persistent.